# MatLab's slow first call of sortrows()

Tags: matlab, sorting

Most times, first call of `sortrows` function in MATLAB is significantly slower than other calls (if it doesn't meet the worst case of sorting I persume). Is it due to loading file with function to compiler? Can I load it earlier in order to make this first call faster?

```
sorting_times = []

for i=1:1:100
        counter=1;
        A=zeros(3);
        for i=1:1:4
            for j=i+1:1:5
                A(licz,1)=i;
                A(licz,2)=j;
                A(licz,3)=randi([20,30]);
                counter=counter+1;
            end
        end
   tic;
   sortrows(A,3);
   sorting_times = [sorting_times toc];
end
plot(sorting_times);
```

[image]

Comment: Use `timeit` for timing, the trusted way.